RNAseq sequence alignment
When I have my RNA sequences and I am going to map them to the reference genome, should I use both haplotypes, use only one, should it be haplotype A?
Could you share some reasons why and or some papers to read about this issue?
I mapped the sequences to both, and each haplotype separately and get different results and would like some help to decide which would be the best choice.
I was expecting to get similar results, but when I map to both haplotype simultaneously I get call for homolog genes, when I mapped only to one of the haplotypes the gene calls change.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like this question is off topic, but there may be sites in the family of stack exchange sites where it could be reworded to be on topic. Please be sure to take the tour of each site to check which questions are on topic and if they have other requirements. I suggest starting with https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/tour
